# how to make *.aj(AspectJ) files be accounted into Sonar-java analysis

Tags: aspectj, sonarqube, sonar-runner

we have a mvn project:

src/main/java/packageA/*.java
src/main/java/packageB/*.aj

but after running sonar , there is only .java file analyzed.
AspectJ is not multi language but is just java byte code injected into already compiled code. So to Sonar it should look just java.

Is there any way to solve this problem?
Is it possible to add some propertise like sonar.java.suffix=.java,.aj...

Answer (score 2):

Even if AspectJ shares most of its syntax with Java, it has special keywords and constructions which are different. So if you customize the "sonar.java.suffix" to include AspectJ files, your analysis will just fail because the Java parser cannot handle aspects.

The only solution would be to develop an AspectJ SonarQube plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it on the settings page or in the `sonar-project.properties` file.

```
1. Go to the settings page
2. Select Java category
3. Select General subcategory
4. Write `.aj` into the inputbox of `File suffixes`
```

OR just add this line to your `sonar-project.properties` file if you use SonarQube runner:

```
sonar.java.file.suffixes=.aj
```

Comment: This won't work: you will have parsing issues and your analysis will fail.